# Using grep to partial match a string

Tags: r, regex

I am looking for a partial matching between two strings, the condition would return true if all words match, but would be false otherwise.
e.g.

```
myElem <- "a b"
```

would return true when matched with

```
nElem <- "a b c"
```

or

```
nElem<- "d g b a",
```

but would return false if

```
nElem <- "d c g a"
```

Can anybody suggest a way using grep or other functions? Thanks in advance.

Also any tutorial for learning the basics of the grep options?

Comment: Provided you want to match *unordered* lists of words, `grep` or another regex tool is not an option. What you want to do can be achieved with a few lines of Python (or any other scripting language of your choice).

Comment: @DavidArenburg My mistake, I missed the `r` tag and didn't know grep was a R function. Still, I think my comment about grep not being suited to this problem applies.

Comment: @RichardScriven, that looks like what the OPs after, I suggest posting it as an answer. Although I never trusted `agrep` too much, it seems bullet proof in this particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `agrepl`? You could adjust the `max.distance` and `costs` arguments if necessary.

```
x <- c("a b c", "d g b a", "d c g a")
agrepl("a b", x)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```